# Embark Demo Issues

Tags: embark, framework

I've been able to open the embark console but I found that there were a few missing messages on the console. It appears that there is "no blockchain" and the status does not show anything. I tried rectifying this issue by inputting embark blockchain in another tab but I got a message which also appears in the log of the embark console.

[image: screen shot 2019-01-10 at 10 08 11]

The page shown above stays like this and does not change. I'm assuming it's because of the issue reflected in the console.

[image: screen shot 2019-01-10 at 10 06 36]

After i input embark run , the console looks like above for a few seconds.

[image: screen shot 2019-01-10 at 10 05 59]

The console then shows the message shown in the image above. I also got this message when I tried to rectify the no blockchain issue by inputting embark blockchain in another tab.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

With the information available it looks like you're running into the issue that Embark (at the moment, 4.0.0-alpha.3 at the time of writing this answer) doesn't support running it without having an Ethereum client installed.

Here's a related issue: https://github.com/embark-framework/embark/issues/982

The [installation guide](https://embark.status.im/docs/installation.html#Ethereum-Client-Optional) claims that it's optional, but this is actually a bug as described in the linked issue.

Do you have a client installed (Geth or Parity)?

Executing `embark run` within the console is not really the way it's supposed to be used. `embark run` effectively spins up the dashboard that you're already running.

See our [Running Apps](https://embark.status.im/docs/running_apps.html) guide for more information.

Also, we're always available on [Gitter](https://gitter.im/embark-framework/Lobby), please ping us there if you need immediate feedback! :)